# Работа this при передачи функции в объект

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, возникла трудность в понимании передачи функции в объект, когда функция использует this.

```js
var user={
  name: 'Example',
  last_name: 'Hm...',
  fullname: sum()
};
  
function sum(){
    return this.name + ' ' + this.last_name; 
  }
  
console.log(user.fullname); //Window undefined
```

Как изменить код, чтобы обратиться не к глобальному объекту а к объекту - user? Почему вообще срабатывает этот механизм

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var user={
  name: 'Example',
  last_name: 'Hm...',
  fullname: sum
};
  
function sum(){
    return this.name + ' ' + this.last_name; 
}
  
console.log(user.fullname());
```

Как я понимаю тут: `fullname: sum()`  вы вызываете функцию, которая как раз вне контекста объекта. А если написать `fullname: sum`, то будете ссылаться на функцию и в определенный нужный момент вы уже её вызываете через `user.fullname()` - где `fullname` как раз лежит в `user`, а значит там уже `this` доступен.